# Set task or pool priority in Gpars

Tags: concurrency, groovy, gpars

I have a few tasks that should be executed with different priorities.
For example, task A is need as soon as possible, but tasks B and C may be calculated a bit later, but definitely after task A.
Moreover, priority of tasks B or C may be changed in future.

How it can be achieved using GPars?

Real business case is that I need to pre-calculate some data. For example, I have 3 tabs, calculation of data for every tab takes 30 seconds. So, I'd like to calculate data for the first tab at the beginning and start to calculate data for the second and third tabs. It is not predictable what tab will be chosen next, so I have to be able to change priority of the second and third tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you tried pools with different thread priorities. Setting a priority for a task then becomes scheduling it on the right pool (or GPars group).

Comment: Vaclav, whether such pool has been already implemented? I tried to found out something similar to it and realized that I may have to write such pool by myself.

Comment: You'll perhaps have to create a new pool with custom thread factory, that adjusts the thread priority. E.g.
`def pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new ThreadFactory() {`
`    @Override`
`    Thread newThread(final Runnable runnable) {`
`        final Thread t = new Thread()`
`        t.setPriority(5)`
`        return t;`
`    }`
`})`